# Matlab: A user-defined accumulator for a matrix

Tags: arrays

Let's assume I have a special function like this:

```
function [sum] = E_add(v1, v2)
```

and another function that I would implement it like this:

```
  acc = 0;
  for ri  = 1 : size(f,1)
      for ci = 1:size(f,2)
          acc = E_add(acc,f(ri,ci));
      end
  end
```

is there any optimized way to do it without for loop, like using `arrayfun`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on my matlab, but are you just looking for sum()?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, `sum()` isn't the thing I'm looking for, it would have worked if the `E_add(v1,v2)` function didn't have a special implementation.

Comment: I'm kind of guessing about what you're trying to do here, but what if instead of the E_add function, you define a function that returns the value that you need when called with a single input, then call arrayfun with that?  Then call sum on the result of your arrayfun() command.  Idk if that ends up being more efficient than a for loop anyway, probably not space wise, but its an idea.  It obviously won't work though if you're stuck using E_add().